# Buck Converter Gate-Source Voltage anomaly

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, control, bootstrap, high-side

I have a desinged a buck converter which has a high side MOSFET, and due that when simulated on ALTIUM the circuit did not work as expected without a bootstrap configuration.

Now with the bootstrap it worked but when I included a feedback loop along with an analog PID controller the pulse signal amplified to mega volts and even gigavolts at the BJT (used instead of the low side MOSFET in the bootstrap) and the duty cycle was not as per the expectations and I was only getting spikes. When I removed the bootstrap and directly connected the output of the controller to the MOSFET, it worked even better. The duty waveform was as per the expectations, however the still the circuit is in a high side configuration without a bootstrap and with Gate voltage < Drain voltage.

When I checked the voltages at the Gate and the Source, the Vgs was > 5V for on-time which means that the circuit technically works fine. What I don't understand is why is the circuit working without the bootstrap increasing the gate voltage to value greater than source as the circuit is still in a high-side configuration?

The Schematic is attached below:
[image]

Comment: Please show a schematic.

Comment: And some links to the component data sheets.

Comment: the schematic has been updated